# Obtain descriptive statistics by group based on users input (Rshiny)

Tags: r, shiny, group-by

I want my shinyApp to display metrics of a dataframe, grouped based on the variable selection made by the user.

For the iris dataset, and using the `library(purrr)` package, you could do it as follows:

```
iris <- iris

iris %>%
  split(.$Species) %>%
  map(summary)
iris$Species
```

However, I'm not sure how to call for this variable inside a reactive function.

Here the RepEx.

```
# Load packages
# Shiny R
library(shiny)
library(purrr)
library(bslib)
library(shinyjqui) # For orderInput widget
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyBS) # For collapsible panels
library(shinybusy) # For busy spinners
library(DT) # For data table outputs
library(psych)

# Data manipulation
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # to drop na
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
library(fastDummies) # Create dummy columns for categorical variables
library(tibble)
library(data.table)
library(readxl)
library(purrr

# Stats
library(stats)
library(effsize)

not_sel <- "Not selected"


ui <- navbarPage(
    tabPanel(
        title = "",
        titlePanel(""),
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
                title = "Inputs",
                fileInput("xlsx_input", "Select XLSX file to import", accept = c(".xlsx")),
                selectInput("group_var", "Grouping variable", choices = not_sel)
            ),
            mainPanel(
                tabsetPanel(
                    tabPanel(
                        title = "",
                        br(),
                        fluidRow(
                            column(6, div(style = "height:40px"),
                                   htmlOutput("stats")
                            ),
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)



# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    # Dynamic selection of the data
    data_input <- reactive({
        #req(input$xlsx_input)
        #inFile <- input$xlsx_input
        #read_excel(inFile$datapath)
        iris
    })
    
    # We update the choices available for each of the variables
    observeEvent(data_input(),{
        # Show choice selection
        choices <- c(not_sel, names(data_input()))
        updateSelectInput(inputId = "group_var", choices = choices)
    })
    
    group_var <- reactive(input$group_var)
    
    ### Generate summary based on group by variable
    
    sum <- reactive({
      data_input() %>%
        split(..data[[group_var()]]) %>%
        map(summary)
    })

    output$stats <- renderTable(
      sum()
    )
    
    
}


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Are all of those `library()` statements really necessary to run this example? Please try to minimize dependencies in examples so we can easily copy/paste the code to run and test it and not have to install a ton of packages just to try to help. Also, please include sample data in the code itself. We don't know what excel files you are testing with so we can't actually run the code to see what it's doing.

Comment: The problem is likely that `split` is a base R function and has no idea about the `.data` pronoun which is tidyverse specific. You can just use `dplyr` commands here like `iris %>% group_by(.data[["Species"]]) %>% group_map(summary)`